# Jtransforms, ouput freq not accurate.

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am working on an app for Google Glass that displays peak current peak frequency in real time(ish) since its recorded audio. My current issue is that the frequency reporting changes very rapidly, so its hard to pinpoint a frequency also I am uncertain if my NumberFormat ouput format is correct as it only ever reaches "00.000". I may need a bit of help with the windowing, but my understanding of it is there.

Thanks!

```
public class RTAactivity extends Activity {

private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;

private TextView tvfreq;
private TextView tvdb;

private RecordingThread mRecordingThread;
private int mBufferSize;
private short[] mAudioBuffer;
private String mDecibelFormat;
private double  mFreqFormat = 0.0;
private int blockSize = 1024;  //4096
private DoubleFFT_1D fft;
private int[] bufferDouble, bufferDouble2;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rta_view);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    tvfreq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_freq);
    tvdb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_decibels);

    // Compute the minimum required audio buffer size and allocate the buffer.
    mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mAudioBuffer = new short[mBufferSize / 2];
    bufferDouble2 = new int[mBufferSize /2];
    bufferDouble = new int[(blockSize-1) * 2 ];

    mDecibelFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.decibel_format);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mRecordingThread = new RecordingThread();
    mRecordingThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mRecordingThread != null) {
        mRecordingThread.stopRunning();
        mRecordingThread = null;
    }
}
private class RecordingThread extends Thread{

    private boolean mShallContinue = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

        AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, mBufferSize);

        short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
        double[] audioDataDoubles = new double[(blockSize * 2)];
        double[] re = new double[blockSize];
        double[] im = new double[blockSize];
        double[] magnitude = new double[blockSize];

        //start collecting data
        record.startRecording();



        DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(blockSize);

        while (shallContinue()) {

            /**decibels */
            record.read(mAudioBuffer, 0, mBufferSize / 2);
            updateDecibelLevel();

            /**frequency */
                ///windowing!?
            for(int i=0;i<mAudioBuffer.length;i++) {
                bufferDouble2[i] = (int) mAudioBuffer[i];
            }

            for(int i=0;i<blockSize-1;i++){
                double x=-Math.PI+2*i*(Math.PI/blockSize);
                double winValue=(1+Math.cos(x))/2.0;
                bufferDouble[i]= (int) (bufferDouble2[i]*winValue); }

               // bufferDouble[2*i]=bufferDouble2[i];
               // bufferDouble[2*i+1] = (int) 0.0;}


            int bufferReadResult = record.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);

            // Read in the data from the mic to the array
            for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                audioDataDoubles[2 * i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16 bit
                audioDataDoubles[(2 * i) + 1] = 0.0;
            }

        //audiodataDoubles now holds data to work with
        fft.complexForward(audioDataDoubles);   //complexForward


        // Calculate the Real and imaginary and Magnitude.

        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            double real = audioDataDoubles[2 * i];
            double imag = audioDataDoubles[2 * i + 1];
            magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt((real * real) + (imag * imag));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            // real is stored in first part of array
            re[i] = audioDataDoubles[i * 2];
            // imaginary is stored in the sequential part
            im[i] = audioDataDoubles[(i * 2) + 1];
            // magnitude is calculated by the square root of (imaginary^2 + real^2)
            magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt((re[i] * re[i]) + (im[i] * im[i]));
        }

        double peak = -1.0;
        // Get the largest magnitude peak
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            peak = magnitude[i];
        }

        // calculated the frequency
        mFreqFormat = (SAMPLING_RATE * peak) / blockSize;
        updateFrequency();

    }

        record.stop();   //stop recording please.
        record.release();  // Deystroy the recording, PLEASE!
    }

    /**true if the thread should continue running or false if it should stop
    */
    private synchronized boolean shallContinue() {return mShallContinue; }

    /** Notifies the thread that it should stop running at the next opportunity. */
    private synchronized void stopRunning() { mShallContinue = false; }


    private void updateDecibelLevel() {
        // Compute the root-mean-squared of the sound buffer and then apply the formula for
        // computing the decibel level, 20 * log_10(rms). This is an uncalibrated calculation
        // that assumes no noise in the samples; with 16-bit recording, it can range from
        // -90 dB to 0 dB.
        double sum = 0;

        for (short rawSample : mAudioBuffer) {
            double sample = rawSample / 32768.0;
            sum += sample * sample;
        }

        double rms = Math.sqrt(sum / mAudioBuffer.length);
        final double db = 20 * Math.log10(rms);

        // Update the text view on the main thread.
        tvdb.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvdb.setText(String.format(mDecibelFormat, db));
            }
        });
    }

  }
           /// post the output frequency to TextView
private void updateFrequency() {
    tvfreq.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NumberFormat nM = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            tvfreq.setText(nM.format(mFreqFormat) + " hz");
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: You need to review your code - you're calculating magnitude twice for some reason (harmless but pointless), but much more importantly your peak finding loop is completely broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code, but the most important one is that your peak finding loop is completely broken - change:

```
    double peak = -1.0;
    // Get the largest magnitude peak
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
        peak = magnitude[i];
    }
```

to:

```
    double peak_val = magnitude[0];   // init magnitude of peak
    peak = 0;                         // init index of peak
    for (int i = 1; i < blockSize; i++) {
        double val = magnitude[i];
        if (val > peak_val) {
            peak_val = val;           // update magnitude of peak
            peak = i;                 // update index of peak
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU PAUL R!  I must say that I become quite a fan of you while building this and learned most from your posts here on SO. I have implemented your fix as noted above and it seems to have solved my issue, I now read 440hz when playing it back through my Klipsch ref speakers! I did note one strange thing that happens though is the readout sometimes jumps up to 43,281hz? Also if you'd like to point out the several other problems I have given myself that would be appreciated. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I am sorry it is actually reading about 10hz off when i play back 440hz i read 430hz, ill double check my calculations and try on another set of speakers tomorrow. Any more ideas would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's at least partly working now. Note that the resolution of your FFT is only 44100/1024 = 43 Hz so your're probably seeing your 440 Hz peak in bin 10 which gives you an estimated frequency of 430 Hz. As for other problems with the code, I already mentioned the redundant magnitude calculations in the comments, but I'll take another look later to see if there is anything else.

Comment: Alright I changed the fft size to 4096 and at 44.1 it seems accurate enough without changing the SampleRate and buffersize. My last concern is the random spikes I am getting at about 43,000hz or so no matter what my test freq is, it reports the freq now at around +/-1-4hz off and then half a second later it spikes to the large freq and goes back to the proper reading.

Comment: With N = 4096 your resolution is now 10.8 Hz, so any frequency estimate has an accuracy of +/- 5.4 Hz. As for "random spikes" - you should probably try displaying your spectrum and/or time domain samples and see if there are any obvious artefacts. It could perhaps be a problem with the way you are capturing your samples (buffer overrun or some such)?

Comment: I also removed the first magnitude calculations, thanks for the heads up, I don't know how i missed that...

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with this Paul, this may be something I should be well aware of but how would I go about display the spectrum / time domain samples. Maybe I need it in more laymen terms?

Comment: I ended up just applying an if statement to the method that updates the frequency, so it only posts and update to the TextView if it is less then or equal to 22khz, to keep it in the audible spectrum.

Comment: I'm not a Java or Android person, so I can't give you specifics, but I expect there are graphics/graph/plotting libraries or APIs that you can use to display a spectrum ?

Answer (score 1):

Added: The frequency resolution of just using the peak magnitude bin of an FFT will be set (quantized) to the sample rate divided by the length of the FFT (44100/1024 Hz for your parameters).  For a short FFT, 430 Hz may be the closest FFT result bin to 440.  To do better, you need to interpolate, use a longer FFT, or use another frequency estimation algorithm.

If you are trying to display pitch frequency (musical pitch or vocal pitch), this is very often not the same a peak spectral frequency from an FFT result.  Look up pitch detection/estimation methods (many academic papers on the topic), as this usually requires a more complicated and robust algorithm than computing the FFT magnitude peak.

Comment: While this is true, and the OP probably needs to do more research, it doesn't address the immediate problem (bugs in the code), so it should probably just be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: My goal here is to just find resonant frequencies. I am an audio engineer and setting up sound systems and ringing them out is something I do daily.  I have spent lots of time doing research to get me this far, if you have any papers that you would recommend to help further my understanding that would be greatly appreciated!